# No result in console, most likely a logical error

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, mean, standard-deviation

I'm relatively new to the world of OOP, and for some reason, the console of IntelliJ and Eclipse doesn't give me an output in the console for the following program. I'm trying to store 12 numbers into an array using scanner and to find the standard deviation, mean, lowest number, and highest number. Can anyone spot what's wrong?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class untitled
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[] grades = new int[12];
        int size = grades.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
        grades[i] = in.nextInt();
        }

        Arrays.sort(grades);
        int low = grades[0];
        int high = grades[11];
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i: grades)
        {
            sum += i;
        }
        int m = sum / size;

        double var = 0;
        double variance;
        double sd;

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            var = var + ((grades[i] - m) * (grades[i] - m));
        }
        variance = (int) var / size;
        sd = Math.pow(variance,.5);


        String lowest = ("Lowest Grade:" + low);
        String highest = ("Highest Grade:" + high);
        String average = ("Average Grade:" + m);
        String standdev = ("Standard Dev.:" + sd);

        System.out.println(lowest);
        System.out.println(highest);
        System.out.println(average);
        System.out.println(standdev);
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What output do you get ?

Comment: I have clearly seen your output.

Comment: Yes the code works fine.

Comment: Just as a little note: this doesn't look much like OOP at all.

Comment: Okay, it seems that I'm clearly not using any OOP concepts, but I'm simply learning how to program right now, and OOP is the path I striving for. It seems I have a lot to learn, and I thank you all for helping me out. 

What I mean is that when I run the code above, there is no output in the console. The console generates nothing at all.

Comment: I am an idiot, and I realized my stupid mistake. The IDE didn't automatically bring up the console, so I never considered to manually open the console and type the numbers in. I just assumed that something didn't work. Thank you all for helping me out. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is to accept 12 inputs.. try entering 12 inputs in console and then your output will appear..

And yeah this doesnt seem to use OOP concepts. Please refer this link for more info regarding OOPS :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming

Comment: Thanks so much. I realized my mistake, and it was stupid of me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you need to enter values first, before the calculation and output can continue. Without having some printed text on the console (like "Enter a new number: ") the console will just stay empty.

You could either enter 12 numbers, or fill the list automatically with `Random` values. In this case the output will immediately be visible on the console.

```
...
nt[] grades = new int[12];
int size = grades.length;

Random random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    grades[i] = random.nextInt(15); // value between 0 and 14
}

Arrays.sort(grades);
int low = grades[0];
...
```

Comment: Ah, I am an idiot. It seemed that the console went up blank because there was no "enter a new number" statement, and I didn't even consider putting in numbers into the console because when clicking run, the console wouldn't appear automatically.